# How to add "fake" attachments in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add my attachments in the table of contents but without having them in my latex file. So I just want to add something like:

```
**Attachments**
Attachment A: interview .............................. 1
Attachment B: worddoc ................................ 5
```

So I can print my Word files seperate from my Latex file.

Thanks in advance

My document:

```
\documentclass[11 pt, twoside, openright, tikz]{report}
\begin{document}
{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\tableofcontents} %error here
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Referenties}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\end{document}
```

Gives the error:

```
Runaway argument?
File ended while scanning use of \contentsline.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.131 \tableofcontents
                      }
```

Comment: Please, test your MWE after deleting the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc`). After compiling twice, there is only a warning about an unused global option `tikz`, no error (with `\\error here` replaced with `% error here`).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I am actually using Overleaf, so i cant remove those files I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Example with page numbers

The attachments are added at the end of the document/table of contents.  Since deferred writing will not work after the last page, the writing is changed to `\immediate\write` by `\zref@wrapper@immediate`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{zref-base}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular chapter}
\section{Regular section}

\clearpage
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \def\addtoc#1#2#3{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
      \protect\contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{%
    \addtoc{chapter}{Attachments}{}%
    \addtoc{section}{Attachment A: interview}{\the\numexpr\value{page}-1+1\relax}%
    \addtoc{section}{Attachment B: worddoc}{\the\numexpr\value{page}-1+5\relax}%
  }%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with page numbers]

### Example without page numbers and dots

`\NoDottedTocLine` is inserted into the `.toc` file to remove the dots.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{zref-base}
\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     % \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
     %    \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
     %    mu$}%
     \hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\NoDottedTocLine}{%
  \let\@dottedtocline\@tocline
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Regular chapter}
\section{Regular section}

\clearpage
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \def\addtoc#1#2#3{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
      \protect\contentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
  \zref@wrapper@immediate{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\NoDottedTocLine}%
    \addtoc{chapter}{Attachments}{}%
    \addtoc{section}{Attachment A: interview}{}%
    \addtoc{section}{Attachment B: worddoc}{}%
  }%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: It gives an error in my code. But somehow Because an other weird error  occurs in my .bib file I cant see the error. But could it give an error because `{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\tableofcontents}`  is in my code?

Comment: @user3201911 There is no MWE in the question. Thus, you have to adapt/apply the code of the answer to your real document. I do not even know, if your document class has chapters (`book`, `report`, ...) or not (`article`, ...).

Comment: okay im sorry I will make a better question about this. It is a report style btw.

Comment: @user3201911 The code in the answer is also based on class `report`. Please, update the question with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I edited a bit of my question